# On second try to open calendar the app crash

Tags: java, android

I have found some strange for me bug in app. When I open calendar ( dialog window ) I can set date. The problem is when I try to open for second time ( open -> close -> open ) the app crash and `Logcat` show this error

```
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Process: com.res, PID: 1023
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.res.CustomDateTimePicker.showDialog(CustomDateTimePicker.java:149)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.res.Reserv$2.onClick(Res.java:75)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-11 12:30:22.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On `CustomDateTimePicker.java:149` I have this `selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);`

```
public void showDialog() {
if (!dialog.isShowing()) {

    datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

    datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 345600000);

    datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

    dialog.show();

    btn_setDate.performClick();
}
}
```

In res.java:75 is this `custom.showDialog();`

```
findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    custom.showDialog();
                }
```

What can be the problem here?
UPDATE

```
custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM) {
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker)).setText(calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "-" + (monthNumber+1) + "-" + year
                                    + " " + hour24 + ":" + min);              
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });

    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    custom.showDialog();
                }
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate `calendar_date`? Can you show the relevant code section? You problem could be that it becomes `null` after you close the dialog.

Comment: Updated my question. Are you talking about this?

Comment: not exactly. Where do you say `Calendar calendar_date = new ...` ?

Comment: This is the full source for customdatetimepicker.java. Is too long to post it in question. Please check it here-> http://pastebin.com/UnifiAWu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem seems to be that `calendar_date` becomes `null` after you close the dialog or `calendar_date` is initialized to `null` and never changed.

Based on the code you posted in the comments, the `showDialog()` function here and in the pastebin are not the same.

In the code in the pastebin you do a check that is missing from this code and that's why you get a [**`NullPointerException`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html):

```
if (calendar_date == null) 
    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Adding the code above should solve your problem.